# When installing Keepnote on Kali Linux 2020.1 get importerror no module name glade

Tags: kali-linux

I have downloaded the keepnote-0.7.8.tar.gz file from keepnote.org for Kali Linux 2020.1
Then did tar zxvf [keepnote file] and then keepnote-0.7.8/bin/keepnote and got ImportError: Mo module named glade.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method below instead.

sudo apt-get install keepnote

https://installlion.com/kali/kali/main/k/keepnote/install/index.html

I find Installion to be very good for the items I have installed in my Kali machine here.

Comment: KeepNote is no more exist on new Kali version 2020, I tested that and package not found.
I saw some people efforts to tweak that by running it inside a docker https://github.com/TH3xACE/keepnote-rip

Answer (score 2):

To install KeepNote on you Kali 2020 version follow these steps:

1. Download the "platform independent" version of it from [here](http://keepnote.org/download-test/keepnote-0.7.9.tar.gz).
2. Run this command to fix all dependencies issues:

   ```
    apt-get install python python-gtk2 python-glade2 libgtk2.0-dev libsqlite3-0
   ```
3. Extract the source code you just downloaded.
4. Enter inside the extracted file and open a terminal on the same page, after that run that command on your terminal:

   ```
    python setup.py install
   ```

   this will install KeepNote on your Kali linux.

Finally, to test your installation, just type in any terminal `keepnote`
and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.